# UITableViewCell doesn't match sectionNameKeyPath property of NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am confused with sectionNameKeyPath, because the tableViewCell are not seperated by the sectionNameKeyPath of fetchResultsController.
Hoping your answer,thanks in advance.

Core data table has a "ctype" property to store "0" or "1"
[image]

and UITableViewController is like this:

```
func configureCell(_ cell: UITableViewCell, withCate catalog:Cate) {
    cell.textLabel!.text = catalog.emoji! + catalog.citem! + catalog.ctype.description  
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let cataitem = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    configureCell(cell, withCate:cataitem)
    return cell
}
```

and the fetchResultsController just like this:

```
let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "ctype", cacheName: "Money")
```

but the objects of the FetchResultController are not separated by ctype.
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

I have got it.
The reason is that I should add a "ctype" sortDescriptors as the first sortDescriptors